# Is there a way to know name clashes in PostScript level between ones used in PSTricks packages and our own definitions?

Tags: pstricks

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=bottom](4,2)
\pstVerb
{
    /a 2 def
    /bb 1 def
}%
\rput(!a bb){First Page}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

My `a` silently overrides the PSTricks' definition. I need a way to know this silent substitution. Is there a way to know name clashes in PostScript level between ones used in PSTricks packages and our own definitions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suppose the correct thing to do is always make your local definitions in a private dictionary to avoid the problem but this postscript addresses the question as asked:

The sequence

```
 dup where {pop == (already defined) ==} {3 def} ifelse
```

will define the preceding token to 3 if it is not defined, and leave it untouched and echo a warning if it is defined.

tested with /a defined to be 2 and /b undefined

```
GS>/a 2 def
GS>/a dup where {pop == (already defined) ==} {3 def} ifelse
/a
(already defined)
GS>a ==
2
GS>/b dup where {pop == (already defined) ==} {3 def} ifelse
GS> b ==
3
```

a gets left as 2 but b is defined to be 3.

Comment: Note in the other answer Herbert shows what I noted above is the "correct thing to do" :-)

Answer (score 7):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}\SpecialCoor
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=bottom](4,2)
\pstVerb
{  userdict begin
    /a 2 def
    /bb 1 def
  end }
\rput(! userdict begin a bb end){First Page}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I used this in my project but I accepted David solution because it conforms to the question.

Comment: Is there a method to avoid repeating `userdict begin ... end` in each points?